# Fixing CSS border-right and border-left issues

Tags: html, css

For some reason, when I implement the `border-left: 10px solid #FF0000` css style for my left column, and the `border-right: 10px solid #FF0000` for my right column, for some reason, it throws everything off...

Anyone know why?

Comment: That's incredibly unspecific. Show us the code of the layout and what do you mean by throws everything off.

Comment: Box model diagram: http://www.456bereastreet.com/i/box-model.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtract 20px from elements width.

Answer (score 1):

"throws everything off" is a little vague, but here is a stab at it. Have you specified a width for the container of your bordered content? Maybe your 10px borders cause your content to be too wide.

If this isn't the problem, please post some more specific info.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the border is added to the width of you element. For example if you have a `100px` div with a `10px` border that will make your element `120px` total.